# How to load data from Cassandra table

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working on Spark version: 2.0.1 and Cassandra 3.9. I want to read data from a table in cassandra by CassandraSQLContext. However, Spark 2.0 was changed and using sparkSession. I am trying to use sparkSession and I am lucky, the following is my code.

Could you please review and give your advice?

```
def main(args: Array[String], date_filter: String): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
     val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local")
      .appName("my-spark-app")
      .config(conf)
      .getOrCreate()
       import sparkSession.implicits._
       import org.apache.spark.sql._
    val rdd = sparkSession
      .read
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .options(Map("table" -> "users", "keyspace" -> "monita"))
      .load() 
      println("count: " +rdd.count())  

  }
```

Comment: Please put your code in a code block so that it's formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok. You don't need to create SC. You can set Cassandra connection properties in config like below.

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession
  .builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("my-spark-app")
  .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
  .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
  .getOrCreate()
```